# Looking for an original citation of Cantor

Tags: real-analysis, math-history

It seems that Cantor rather than Cauchy suggested the Cauchy equivalence class definition of $\mathbb{R}$.  I am looking for the original book or paper (for whomever originally suggested the Cauchy definition.)  My question is: what is the citation for this original source?

Comment: Move this question to https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ where it fits in better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Cantor's definition of real number](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy+real+number):

> Georg Cantor, [Ueber die Ausdehnung eines Satzes aus der Theorie der trigonometrischen Reihen (1872)](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Cantor/Ausdehnung/).

Comment: Thanks!  You are a cool guy!

Comment: @JimmyRankerman - you are welcome :-)